# how to add a Client in SCCM system collections

Tags: sccm

I am building a new sccm client VM. My only doubt is how to add the system name of the client to all systems collections before building the OS.

Many Thanks in advance. :)

Kind Regards,
Yuvi

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in configuration manager console by going to SCCM | Site Database | Computer Management | Operating System Deployment | Computer Association.  Right-click on this node and select Import Computer Information.  You can then associate the new machine by its MAC address.